# Dependency failed for Docker Application Container Engine

Tags: docker, chef-infra

My docker is not getting started. Also it is throwing below error. This issue is coming in **RHEL** server. Please help me to solve this issue.

```
Aug 01 00:24:07 rhelserver006 systemd[45452]: Failed to chown socket at step GROUP: No such process
Aug 01 00:24:07 rhelserver006 systemd[1]: docker.socket control process exited, code=exited status=216
Aug 01 00:24:07 rhelserver006 systemd[1]: Failed to listen on Docker Socket for the API.
-- Subject: Unit docker.socket has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
--
-- Unit docker.socket has failed.
--
-- The result is failed.
Aug 01 00:24:07 rhelserver006 systemd[1]: Dependency failed for Docker Application Container Engine.
-- Subject: Unit docker.service has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
--
-- Unit docker.service has failed.
--
-- The result is dependency.
Aug 01 00:24:07 rhelserver006 systemd[1]: Job docker.service/start failed with result 'dependency'.
Aug 01 00:24:07 rhelserver006 systemd[1]: Unit docker.socket entered failed state.
Aug 01 00:24:11 rhelserver006 adclient[1905]: INFO  <bg:run-queue> sam.loader DB: /var/centrifydc/dz.cache.new update successfully
```

Comment: This doesn't look like it is Chef related unless I'm missing something.

Comment: @coderanger thanks for reply based on this thread https://github.com/chef-cookbooks/docker/issues/603 it is related to the chef-client.This is almost same.

Comment: Are you actually using Chef though?

Comment: Is this a fresh machine or you had docker installed and recently it was updated?

Comment: @TarunLalwani Docker was already there.

Comment: Remove docker and prune the config files and reinstall it. See if it works

Answer (score 3):

docker group does not exist. Run `useradd docker` and then rerun.